# Getting access token from facebook SDK in iOS

Tags: facebook, ios5

Is it possible to get the access token for the logged in user in iOS 5? If so, how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using the current version (v3.2.1 at this time) of the SDK you can get to the user's access token with the following:

`[[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken]`

Answer (score 0):

Visit for more details about ios authentication :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/

http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

Comment: :Thanks fo this info, I will check it out.